# Office ui fabric Dropdown reads selected item on component focus

Tags: accessibility, office-ui-fabric

I am using office ui fabric react v 6.174.0.

I am using the dropdown component, and currently testing the accessibility. Let's say the menu has the following options:

1. Apple [selected]
2. Orange
3. Banana

When I focus the menu (before opening/expanding it), the narrator reads the following:

> Apple selected. Selection contains 3 items. Apple. 1 of 3. Selected.

What I would like it to read is this:

> Apple selected. Selection contains 3 items.

The added text is actually what is read when menu is opened and the Apple is focused. As I understand, this is because the dropdown component treats the items as if they were in the DOM, even when they aren't (from reading [this](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/5473) thread on github). However, I would still like the item to only be read when it is explicitly focused while the menu is opened.

Is there an easy, non-hacky way to do this?

I am currently trying to hack my way around, making the whole component aria-hidden, and adding a surrounding div that will read only the text I want, but would prefer a less hacky way.